# Web service to alert me if my server fails

Tags: web-services, web-server

For a personal web server hosting a single application, there's the possibility of the hardware failing, and I might not realize for a week or more.
I have alerts in my programs but they require internet, power, working hardware, etc.

Purpose

- A web service that listens for packets from servers and if they don't arrive for x hours in a row, emails the owner.

Requirements

- Less than $13 per year.

Comment: So far the two recommendations provide for receiving a ping but not for sending one.

Comment: Why do you need a webservice? Indeed why can't you check this yourself from home with a bash script and a cronjob?

Comment: @user193661 What do you mean by sending a ping? When the service "pings" your website, it does send data including an HTTP request to your server

Comment: @Tom I was thinking that if a user has multiple devices to monitor on a LAN with dynamic IP address and behind a router, with no DNS or IP configuration, it would be more convenient for their devices to be the senders. So they send HTTP POST requests, including a user code, to the monitoring service.

Comment: I think that `uptimerobot` is actually the best solution for all those cases though and that's the one I'm using. Even for a device that changes network location, it would be best for it to just reconfigure its DNS.

Comment: `uptimerobot` supports custom ports which makes it more useful than `newrelic` for me.

Comment: Great, I glad one of them worked out:)

Comment: I've accepted an answer but if anyone has a recommendation, please add it to the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another service I have used,

## [UptimeRobot](http://uptimerobot.com/)

> Monitors your websites every 5 minutes, totally free. Get alerts by
>   e-mail, SMS, Twitter or RSS. Add up to 50 websites. Monitors can be
>   refreshed for an instant check with a click. Supports https and
>   authentication with user/password.
>
> Relatively modern UI.
>
> The free account
>
> - supports up to 50 monitors
> - no SMS notifications
> - doesn't support escalations (e.g. when the first contact to respond doesn't acknowledge the downtime, a second contact is alerted). Use
>     BinaryCanary for that.

Paid accounts starts at $4.50 per month

[image: UptimeRobot UI]

Answer (score 4):

## [NewRelic Synthetics](http://newrelic.com/synthetics/)

NewRelic Synthetics I think is exactly what your looking for. With this service you can,

- 50 Free "Pings" and with "pings" you can
- 24 Hour Data Retention
- Plan last forever (*not* a trial)
- Set checking intervals as low as 1 minute
- Up to 9 monitoring locations all over the world
- Set text within the webpage for the ping to check for
- Setup email alerts
- Monitoring includes results like,

  - Load time over different monitoring locations
  - Cool looking graphs

[image: NewRelic Synthetics UI]

Comment: Integrate slack with NewRelic and you get notifications on your device/phone when things go bad. Wonderful feature: https://slack.com/